# Salesforce: Can a Javascript Remoting Static Function Access ApexPages.CurrentPage Functions?

Tags: cookies, static, salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I was wondering, In a RemoteAction function in an apex class can or should this be able to access the current force.com site page?  I would like to access and write to cookie parameters from within my static remote method but I'm guessing this may not be possible?
If not, any suggestions on how to get around this would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you join us on salesforce.stackexchange.com ?Thats an awesome site as well to post questions related to salesforce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote Action method runs in an.asynchronous mode.Hence accessing values from url parameter will get you null values.If you need any static values for your apex class to process use the parameters.pass from page to your apex method using parameter .

There is one way that i recently discovered to do this

Pass them in from the script on the page using {!$currentpage.parameters.something}

You still need to check for nulls in the code because it might legitimately be null